# Scrapy shell debug doesn't show items

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy 0.22. I have a spider that uses an item loader to extract an item. When I run the spider from scrapy shell, I see only debug messages containing None instead of the item from my item loader.

> 2014-01-26 20:33:08+0100 [ChatroomSpider] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://somedomain.com/?a=chat_rooms>
>       None

However, if I uncomment the `#print item`line, I can see the item printed to stdout as expected.

Spider:

```
class ChatroomSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'ChatroomSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['somedomain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://somedomain.com/?a=chat_rooms']

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        for chatroom_div in selector.xpath(r'id("body")/div[count(div) = 4 and div/div]'):
            loader = ChatroomLoader(chatroom_div)
            chatroom = loader.load_item()
            #print chatroom
            yield chatroom
```

Loader:

```
class ChatroomLoader(XPathItemLoader):

    default_item_class = ChatRoomItem

    name_in = Encode(encoding='utf-8')
    name_out = TakeFirst()

    description_in = StripAndEncode(encoding='utf-8')
    description_out = TakeFirst()

    datetime_in = StrpTime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
    datetime_out = TakeFirst()

    def __init__(self, room_selector):
        super(ChatroomLoader, self).__init__(selector=room_selector)

        self.add_xpath('name', r'div[1]/div/font/b/a/text()')
        self.add_xpath('description', r'div[2]/div/text()')
        self.add_xpath('users', r'div[3]/div/a/font/text()')
        self.add_xpath('datetime', r'id("copyright")/text()[4]', re=r'[0-3]?[0-9].[0-2][0-9].201[3-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]')
```

Comment: Are you not using `.add_xpath()` or `.add_value()` calls after the ItemLoader instantiation? I don't understand how `chatroom` can have meaningful data if you don't (or you only provided only part of your spider code)

Comment: @pault. Good point. I added the code for the loader as well.

Comment: @prasopes are you using custom pipeline?

Comment: @sardok Oh. I see the problem now. My pipeline wasn't returning the items, but I never noticed that as it was storing items directly to DB. Care to post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your own pipeline, make sure that, item is returned from it.

For more information about pipelines; http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html